Strong Liouville property of virtually abelian groups
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and let $\mu$ be a symmetric non-degenerate measure on $G$. By strong Liouville property for $(G, \mu)$, we mean that every positive $\mu$-harmonic function on $G$ is constant. I have a very basic question: what is the most broad class of measures $\mu$ for which virtually abelian groups are known to be strong Liouville? What I know is that even virtually nilpotent groups are strong Liouville if the associated measure is finitely supported, as in Hebisch and Saloff-Coste - Gaussian Estimates for Markov Chains and Random Walks on Groups.
Is something better known for virtually abelian groups, particularly without a measure that is not finitely supported? This is mainly a reference request.

You need to assume that the measure is symmetric to get the strong Liouville property, even for finitely supported random walks on abelian groups

Assuming that the random walk is symmetric on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, you just need finite moments of order $2r>\max(2,d-2)$ to get that the Martin boundary is reduced to a point, and so in particular every positive harmonic function is constant. I don't know yet if these assumptions are optimal

@M.Dus Edited to include the symmetry assumption. Suppose we add the conditions of exponential, or superexponential or even Gaussian moments. Is the strong Liouville property known to be true even then?

I will write a more complete answer.

I see that you added a symmetry assumption, but I'm still answering your original question, for sake of completeness.
So first of all, the following remark is very important. The probability measure $\mu$ on $G$ has the strong Liouville property if and only if the minimal Martin boundary is reduced to a point. Indeed, one direction is obvious : if all positive harmonic functions are constant, then the only possible minimal Martin kernel can be the constant function $\mathbf{1}$. The converse is obtained by the Poisson-Martin representation theorem combined with the fact the constant function $\mathbf 1$ is always a minimal harmonic function in nilpotent groups (in fact $\mathbf 1$ being minimal exactly means that bounded harmonic functions are constant, so this last fact is true for any random walk on a group satisfying the (standard) Liouville property).
Now, I'm focusing on the case where $G=\mathbb Z^d$. Introduce the function
$$\Phi(u)=\sum_{x\in \mathbb Z^d}\mu(x)\mathrm{e}^{u\cdot x}.$$
Then, the $t$-minimal Martin boundary coincides with the level set $\Phi(u)=t$. More precisely, the $t^{-1}$-minimal Martin kernels are exactly the exponential functions $x\in \mathbb Z^d\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{u\cdot x}$ with $\Phi(u)=t$. This is Theorem 25.4 in Woess' book Random walks on infinite graphs and groups. This is in fact true for $\mathbb Z^d$-invariant Markov chains on finite extensions of $\mathbb Z^d$, so in particular this is true for random walks on virtually abelian groups. The $\mathbb Z^d$-invariance property is precisely condition (6.2) in the aforementioned reference.
Note that you do not need any assumption on the support and on the moments of the random walk. But assuming that the support is finite, it is easy to prove that the function $\Phi$ is strictly convex on $\mathbb R^d$ and so away from its minimum, the level sets are homeomorphic to a $d-1$-dimensional sphere. Therefore, the $t$-minimal Martin boundary is a $d-1$-dimensional sphere if $t$ is not the minimum of $\Phi$ and the $t_0$-minimal Martin boundary is reduced to a point if $t_0$ is the minimum of the function $\Phi$.
Since we are interested in the 1-minimal Martin boundary being reduced to a point (property which is equivalent to strong Liouville property by what precedes), we need to look if $1$ is the minimum of $\Phi$. Note that $\Phi(0)=1$. By strict convexity, the minimum is reached at $u_0$ where $\nabla \Phi(u_0)=0$ and this points is unique. Consequently, the 1-minimal Martin boundary is reduced to a point if and only if $\nabla \Phi(0)=0$.
Now,
$$\nabla \Phi(0)=\sum_{x\in \mathbb Z^d}x\mu(x)=\mathbb E[X],$$
where $X$ is a random variable with distribution given by $\mu$. This is exactly the drift of the random walk. Therefore, with the finite support assumption, the minimal Martin boundary is reduced to a point, i.e. one has the strong Liouville property if and only if the random walk is centered. This is true in particular if it is symmetric.
One direction of this last result still hold assuming only that $\mu$ has finite first moment. That is, if $\mu$ has finite first moment and zero drift, then it has the strong Liouville property. This is Corollary 25.5 in Woess' book.
One small remark : the minimum of the function $\Phi$ is the spectral radius $\rho$ of the random walk. So 1 being the minimum of $\Phi$ really means that $\rho=1$. In fact what is true is the following : if $\rho=1$, then every positive harmonic function is constant, see the comments before Corollary 25.5. Now, if $\mu$ has finite first moment, zero-drift implies $\rho=1$, but you do not need finite first moment, what really matters is $\rho=1$. Finally, if $\mu$ is symmetric, you automatically get that $\rho=1$, this is Corollary 12.12 in Woess' book.
Consequently, to answer your edited question (with the symmetry assumption added) : if $\mu$ is symmetric on $\mathbb Z^d$, then it has the strong Liouville property without any condition on the moments. And as explained, this is also true for virtually abelian groups.
An interesting fact is that one can construct an example where $\mu$ is not symmetric and in fact has a positive drift on $\mathbb Z$, but still has the strong Liouville property, see Exercise 25.7. Hint for this exercise : with the notations before the exercise, take $a_1=a_2=1$, $b_1=3$, $b_2=2$ and choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ so that $\Phi(0)=1$ ($\mu$ needs to be a probability measure), $\Phi(1)<1$ (so that the level set $\Phi=1$ is reduced to $\{0\}$ and so $\mu$ has the strong Liouville property) and $\Phi'(0)<1$, so that $\mu$ is not centered.
Finally, let me explain a bit how this machinery works for nilpotent groups. Let $G$ be nilpotent, let $H=[G,G]$ be its commutator subgroup and let $A=G/H$ be its abelianization.
Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $G$ and consider the push-forward measure $\nu$ on $A$, given by
$$\nu(xH)=\sum_{h\in H}\mu(xh).$$
A landmark result of Margulis states that all positive harmonic functions are constant on the cosets of $H$. This is Corollary 25.9 in Woess' book.
A direct consequence of Margulis' result is that the minimal Martin boundary of $\mu$ on $G$ coincides with the minimal Martin boundary of $\nu$ on $A$ (you need to check that a minimal harmonic function for $\mu$, which is constant on the cosets of $H$, still defines a minimal harmonic function on $A$ and conversely).
As a consequence, the minimal Martin boundary of $\mu$ is reduced to a point (strong Liouville property for $(G,\mu)$) if and only if the minimal Martin boundary of $\nu$ is reduced to a point (strong Liouville property for $(A,\nu)$).
Finally, it is easy to see that if $\mu$ is symmetric, the same property holds for $\nu$. Consequently, assuming that $\mu$ is symmetric, it has the strong Liouville property, this is Corollary 25.10 in Woess' book.

Excellent answer! Quick question: You seem to have given a proof for the case when $G$ is nilpotent. Does this cover the case when $G$ is virtually Abelian? My reason for asking this question is that virtually Abelian groups might not in general be nilpotent, or maybe I am missing something?

@M. Dus After your reply I am leafing through Woess' book. Doesn't Corollary 25.10 actually answer my question? Virtually abelian implies polynomial growth, and in particular it is amenable. Then the spectral radius $\rho$ is equal to $1$. Or do I misunderstand something?

@SMS You are right, but it is a bit strange to apply Corollary 25.10, which is for virtually nilpotent group if you are interested in virtually abelian groups. Especially since the proof for virtually nilpotent groups consists in going to the abelianization and then using the result for virtually abelian groups. Anyway, you are right that one does not need finite first moment and I edited my question.

@piper1967  Virtually abelian does not imply nilpotent, you are right (just take a finite non-nilpotent group $G_0$ and consider $G=\mathbb Z^d×G_0$). But the case for virtually abelian groups is also covered by the results I stated, as explained at the end of the third paragraph of my answer. Because any virtually abelian group can be considered, as a set, as a finite extension of $\mathbb Z^d$. More precisely, if $H$ is a finite index subgroup of $G$ which is abelian, then $H=\mathbb Z^d\times F$, where $F$ is finite (we are assuming that groups are finitely generated). ...

@piper1967 ... and then any section $\mathbb Z^d \to G$ givens an identification $G=\mathbb Z^d\times F'$, where $F'$ is a finite set (although not necessarily a group anymore). Now, any probability measure on $G$ yields a Markov chain on $\mathbb Z^d\times F'$ which is $\mathbb Z^d$-invariant. This is why I claimed in my answer that the result for $\mathbb Z^d$-invariant chains on finite extensions of $\mathbb Z^d$ gives the result for virtually abelian groups. Finally notice that the remainder of Chapter 25, especially Corollary 25.10 actually covers the case of a virtually nilpotent group.

@M.Dus I am confused about one minor point. In the statement of Corollary 25.10, Woess first assumes polynomial growth for a weaker conclusion and then $\rho = 1$ for a stronger conclusion. For a Cayley graph, polynomial growth implies $\rho = 1$. So does that mean there exist graphs which have polynomial growth but $\rho < 1$?

@SMS Yes of course, if you do not assume symmetry. In the case of a finitely supported random walk in $\mathbb Z^d$, this is clear from my answer : $\rho$ is the minimum of the function $\Phi$ and 1 is the minimum if and only if the random walk is centered.

@SMS Your claim that polynomial growth implies $\rho=1$ is not true. It is true assuming further that the Markov chain is symmetric, or more generally reversible. Let me clarify what is true about amenability : non-amenability implies $\rho<1$ whether $\mu$ is symmetric or not. amenability + reversibility implies $\rho=1$.
